# NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting the above mentioned error and do not know why because I implemented the same code in another example. "services" is my NSMutableArray and "service name" is the label on table view with Tag 2. In viewdidload I fill the service array with objects.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"servicesCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    UILabel *servicesName;
    UILabel *nrofService;
    if(tableView == self.servicetable)
    {
        servicesName = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:2];
        servicesName.text = [[services objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];            
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You are expecting array at services. But it is retuning string. 
[services objectAtIndex:0] returning string not array.

Comment: yes, and I am setting that string to label text. How can I fix that?

Comment: Array returning a string so before setting text value you can check the class type **  ,if ([[services objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                            servicesName.text = [[services objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                        } **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the below line:

```
servicesName.text = [[services objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Check `[services objectAtIndex:0]` is returning `NSString` instead of `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`. So you are calling `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` on `NSString` which causes the exception:

> NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

So set your UILabel text as below:

```
servicesName.text = [services objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your help.